# What are the units of the measurements that come out of an accelerometer?

Tags: accelerometer

I'm pulling samples out of [this](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00042751.pdf) accelerometer that I've configured for high resolution mode:

[image]

and I'm trying to understand the units of what's coming out.  Some places online seem to indicate just `au` (arbitrary units), some say `mV / g`, and this seems to indicate `mg`.  When I gather samples, I see values go beyond 2000 which makes me think I'm exceeding the range I configured for.

I also realize there are different types of accelerometers but can't seem to find out which type this one is.  Is there a way to map the units to something more meaningful than `au`'s?

Comment: Under what circumstances to you see values beyond 2000? Static or accelerating? Is 'g' gravitational acceleration (9.81 m/s)?

Comment: static.  I move from one orientation, slowly to another axis.  I see 0g happen when I expect, but otherwise I see ~+/-15000 for pointed down and pointed up.

Comment: With 12 bit it can not give you values over +/- 2048. Are you shure to read the value right?

Comment: I've actually used LIS2DH on another project, let me check my notes... this was in my opinion a very confusing datasheet.

Comment: Oooh.  I may have a C error outside the scope of this question.  I'm bit shifting an `int16_t` not a `uint16_t` and I think the sign bit is being preserved.

Comment: By the way, don't bother trying to use the temperature sensor on the LIS2DH -- it can read out a somewhat relative temperature, but doesn't seem to give a repeatable absolute temperature. (Nor do they claim any meaningful temperature accuracy, if you read the datasheet very closely.) This drove me nuts when I was getting started on this product, because I thought to try one of the "easy" measurements before tackling the more complicated accelerometer.

Comment: Page 10, chapter 2 of the datasheet you link yourself: super easy table telling you exactly how many mili-g-force per digit of the read number depending on your settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to see the reading in meaningful units.  Your resolution is 12 bits, so you have 4096 A/D counts across the dynamic range.  I'll also assume that you have selected dynamic range of ±2g.

Then the value of one A/D count is
4 [g] / 4096 = 0.0009765625 [g/count] ≈ 1 [mg/count]

+1g corresponds to 1024 counts.

Comment: Watch the zero-g level offset though, see datasheet page 10 `TyOff` +/-40 mili"g"  typical; but no guaranteed min/max offset. Software should be prepared to null this offset, if it's significant in your application.

Comment: When we did some "beta testing" with this accelerometer attached  to a user running on a treadmill, the +/-2g range was not sufficient -- we had to use +/-8g. However sitting at a desktop, +/-2g works fine.

Answer (score 3):

On the LIS2DH, the 16-bit register paris `OUT_X_H` / `OUT_X_L`, `OUT_Y_H` / `OUT_Y_L`, `OUT_Z_H` / `OUT_Z_L` are left-justified, regardless of which resolution is selected. In other words, the 0x80 bit of OUT_X_H will be 0 or 1 indicating whether the X vector is pointing one direction or the other.

The actual physical units are determined in terms of the *Full-Scale* range (in `CTRL_REG4[1:0]` also called `FS1:FS0`). Note that they use the small "g" to indicate the force of gravity at earth surface, 9.8 m/s^2. (Not grams of mass.) When full-scale is set to 2g, the OUT_X_H bit 6 means 1g, bit 5 means 0.5g, bit 4 means 0.25g, bit 3 means 0.125g, and so on.

The resolution determines how many of the measurement bits are valid. In 8-bit and 10-bit modes, fewer bits are determined. The highest resolution mode only determines 12 bits, OUT_X_H[7:0] and OUT_X_L[7:4]. The unused sub-LSBs of OUT_X_L are 0.